# ¿Cómo hacer que jQuery signature que funcione en el móvil?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery, signature

Tengo una pagina con un formulario que la persona tiene que firmar el formulario. En el navegador anda perfecto pero en el móvil no funciona, solo deja clicar y poner puntitos, no se puede firmar. Estoy usando en plugin de jQuery signature. Me gustaría saber como hago para que funcione también en el móvil, si es posible.

Dejo mi código:

```js
var sig = $('#sig').signature({syncField: '#signature64', syncFormat: 'PNG'});
    $('#clear').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        sig.signature('clear');
        $("#signature64").val('');
    }
);
```

```css
.kbw-signature { width: 100%; height: 200px;}

#sig canvas{
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">  
<label class="" for="">Firma:</label>
<br/>
<div id="sig"></div>
<br/>

<button id="clear">Limpiar</button>
<textarea id="signature64" name="signed" style="display: none;"></textarea>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.signature.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/jquery.signature.css">
```

Comment: Es posible que el plugin jQuery Signature no esté diseñado para funcionar correctamente en los móviles. Puedes intentar a utilizar una biblioteca que tenga soporte para eventos táctiles, como por ejemplo "Hammer.js". También puedes intentar hacer que el canvas se ajuste correctamente al tamaño de la pantalla del dispositivo móvil. Por ejemplo, estableciendo el ancho y la altura del canvas en porcentajes en lugar de píxeles fijos.

Comment: Hola, Hammer,js no conocía, y los porcentajes ya los cambie y sigue igual

Comment: Hola! Muy probablemente el problema sea lo que mencionan arriba (plugin no está diseñado para eso)... Por si te sirve, este es el que yo he usado para computadora/teléfonos
http://keith-wood.name/signature.html

Comment: Intenta hacerlo con `vanilla` _`JS` puro_... En laweb existen recursos que te guian en el paso a apaso, [como este, por ejemplo](https://parzibyte.me/blog/2021/09/09/solicitar-firma-manuscrita-javascript/)